# Why Appstore keeps asking me to provide NSCalendarsUsageDescription even though I already have that at my plist?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm currently developing an app that requires several permissions to run properly, such as permission to use `camera`, `gallery`, `mic`, and `calendar`. I already added `NSCameraUsageDescription`, `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`, and `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` into the plist. But when I upload the binary to Appstore / itunesconnect, it sends an email stating that:

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

[image]

It's strange, I don't get any issue with the others (Camera, Photo Gallery, and Microphone). Why I keep getting one for the Calendar?

Comment: You need to add clear description like **We need to access calendar to add Event or get event**. Apple reject because of this **This feature requires access to phone calendar**

Comment: @ChenLiYoung, You should provide an appropriate message for using Calendar **( This feature.... what feature??).** Also do not include Microphone usage permission if your app is not using it.